# Can laptop battery get damaged if charged from non grounded outlet?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, ground

Recently I noticed my laptop battery swelled large amounts a lot on both top and bottom. It is an internal battery and 2+ years old. I have suspicion that using a power outlet without earthing/grounding is the problem.

The outlet I am using has 3 holes but it is not grounded. The laptop safety manual mentions to not insert it into a non-grounded outlet. This question matches some of the conditions, [How to protect laptop if my outlet isn't grounded?](https://superuser.com/questions/524333/how-to-protect-laptop-if-my-outlet-isnt-grounded).

Earlier I used it with grounding and did not notice any big shape changes to battery but used last 2-3 months used without grounding. Also left it to charge whole night. **Could it be the reason why the battery swelled?**

One confusing thing is manufacturer diagnostic software shows that battery is in good health. Also on my test even in this condition the battery is somehow able to hold charge for 1-1.5+ hours depending on usage. **How?**

Answer (score 3):

The connection to the wall AC outlet is not likely to cause the battery to swell. If the AC adapter has a two prong plug, it does not matter which way around it is plugged in.

If the AC adapter has 3 prongs (one ground) it will be inserted to the power connectors the correct way.

Swelling (if it occurs) is normally from continued charging to a very high charge level and left connected.  I do not see swelling very often. A swollen battery can leak because of the swelling.

Leaving a computer connected to AC should be limited to around 75 to 80% charge.

It also simply could be the battery age (no guarantee as to specifically how long any battery will last).

I suggest you replace the battery as soon as you can (leaking as I noted earlier), and then not leave it plugged into AC all the time.

Comment: I agree with your synopsis, except the last line.  It is dangerous to continue to use a swollen battery, and it should be replaced immediately - and that its dangerous should be made clear.

Comment: Thank you. I made an edit to my post to reflect the danger and your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. Up voted your answer. I am looking for further clarification on how battery is still able to hold that much charge and why using an outlet for which ground pin is just for show(the slot is there just for 3 prong plug compatibility) does not harm battery.

Comment: (a) How much charge a battery can hold is dependent on the battery itself. It can still function if swollen.  (b) The electrical outlet is independent of the computer. We cannot tell why a prior person put in a 3 pin outlet. That is maybe all they had or could get - not good practice.  (c) The battery should really be replaced right away.  I hope this clarifies for you.